# Netbeans 7 does not recognize Subversion 1.8 working copy

Tags: svn, netbeans-7

I've just updated my PC and installed Windows 7 64-bit and also installed TortoiseSVN 1.8.13. It uses SVN 1.8, so it asked me to upgrade my working copy of J2EE. It was previously from SVN 1.7.
Now the problem is, whenever I try to see the changes or refresh / update the working copy from Netbeans, SVN fails with error, however from the filesystem it works without any errors.

Any reasons for these failures? How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by crashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subversion 1.8 working copy won't be recognized by Subversion 1.7 client, that's why [`svn upgrade`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.upgrade.html) or a clean working copy checkout is required after upgrading from the client from Subversion 1.7 to 1.8. Therefore, make sure that your Netbeans instance [supports Subversion 1.8](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSubversion1_8)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am using Netbeans 7.2 which doesn't have support for subversion 1.8(which I noticed only after your response). I installed subversion 1.7 and checked out a fresh copy from subversion and manually replaced my local working files.